# Injecting Env variable from initContainer to the main container before its ENTRYPOINT starts

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables

This has been asked in some other forms, but here's the situation:

I wanna pass an env variable from a (init)container to the other (main) container before it's ENTRYPOINT gets executed (meaning I don't wanna overwrite the main container's ENTRYPOINT)

a sample pod manifest for simplicity looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
    - name: maincontainer
      image: nginx
      ports:
      - containerPort: 80
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      volumeMounts:
      - name: my-volume
        mountPath: /var2
  initContainers:
    - name: initcontainer
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      image: curlimages/curl
      command: ["bin/sh"]
      # pass the env variable to a (mounted) file ... this needs to be `source`d in the main container
      args: ["-c", "echo NEWENV=var > /var/log/mynewlog.env ; sleep 100"]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: my-volume
        mountPath: /var/log
  volumes:
  - name: my-volume
    emptyDir: {}
```

the main container's ENTRYPOINT essentially reads the env variable, and since it's been used by multiple services, I don't wanna change the Dockerfile/how `ENTRYPOINT` is implemented.

If there was a way to ensure I can run a script just after the maincontianer starts (and before it's ENTRYPOINT) it would've been perfec  ...  but unfortunately [PostStart](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks) hook does not guarantee that.

Another potential solution (which I need to investigate more) is to somehow create a configmap from within initContainer and inject the data/env variable, which will be read/referenced from the main container's `env` filed.

Any suggestion/feedback how to tackle this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What sort of value is computed by the init container?  I feel like you've defined the problem to exclude every straightforward way of doing this.  (If the `ENTRYPOINT` is a typical shell-script wrapper that `exec "$@"` the container `CMD`, it's three lines to read the environment file if it exists.)

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT` differs for each microservice - there are a bunch of them which I don't wanna deal with since that looks like a big migration. I was hoping to solve this issue at a higher level

`initContainer` will eventually end up reading a secret from vault and modifies that value to pass it to the main container, but I was trying figure out if there's a way to pass/share the env var to the main container.